# Does AWS Aurora suffer from the same limitations that MySQL suffer from?

Tags: mysql, aws

Specifically, MySQL has a limitations max row size as 64kB. I would like to know if Amazon Aurora, which is supposedly a drop in replacement for MySQL suffer the same limitation.

Comment: You should probably confirm that with Amazon.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

There is no limitation of 64KB on the size of a MySQL row.  There are limitations, but almost never does anyone hit them.  Can you point to where you got that limit?

There are a couple of obscure limits in InnoDB, such as having dozens of big `VARCHARs`, but they are easily worked around.

Here are the main limits for MySQL:  http://mysql.rjweb.org/doc.php/limits

**Edit**

At first glance the [manual page on row size](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.6/en/column-count-limit.html) says there is a 64K limit on row size, but reading further it says "BLOB and TEXT columns count from one to four plus eight bytes each toward the row-size limit because their contents are stored separately from the rest of the row."  Since `LONGBLOB` and `LONGTEXT` columns can contain up to 4GB *each*, the maximum total row size (including such columns) is at least 4GB.

Furthermore, "stored separately" is dependent on the `ENGINE` involved; that quote does not cover all the cases.

The bottom line is that it is possible to create a table with more than 64KB of data.  (I don't know about exceeding 4GB.)  Doing so may require using `TEXT` instead of `VARCHAR(65535)` (which is virtually identical in semantics), etc.

I have made many tables (MyISAM and InnoDB) where the "row size" was bigger than 64KB, both in definition and in fact.  I have multiple cases of `MEDIUMTEXT` or `MEDIUMBLOB` that work fine, back at least as far as version 4.0.

Comment: http://dev.mysql.com/doc/mysql-reslimits-excerpt/5.6/en/column-count-limit.html

Comment: In the link I posted it says there is a limit on row size

Comment: That page is unnecessarily scary.  See my edit.

Comment: Thanks for the clarification. Just one more doubt. Do you think there would be any performance hit in using blob instead of varchar if my schema might have to use a lot of blobs.

Comment: `BLOB` ~= `VARBINARY`; `TEXT` ~= `VARCHAR`.  The latter two check `CHARACTER SET`, hence good for text.  The former two are better for images and other non-text stuff.  For complex `SELECTs` that need a tmp table, `VARCHAR(up to 255?)` is better than `TINYTEXT`.  (Ditto for Binary/blob).  Please show us the tentative `CREATE TABLE`; there may be other subtle issues relating to "performance hit".